# Response body not being serialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an ActiveModel Serializer that changes the fields names to lowerCamelCase. But It's not working on my response.body when I try test it on rspec

```rb
ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
  config.key_format = :lower_camel
end

class DevelopmentAgentsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :phone
end

class DevelopmentAgentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @development_agents = DevelopmentAgent.all

    render json: @development_agents
   end
 end

it "returns a list of development agents" do
  get :index, format: :json

  expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(JSON.parse({development_agents: serialized_development_agent}.to_json))  
end
```

**expected**: `{"development_agents"=>[{"id"=>3, "name"=>"Some name", "email"=>nil, "createdAt"=>"2019-08-06T17:30:47.372-03:00", "updatedAt"=>"2019-08-06T17:30:47.372-03:00", "phone"=>"(21)999999999"}]}`

**got**:
 `{"development_agents"=>[{"id"=>3, "name"=>"Some name", "email"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2019-08-06T17:30:47.372-03:00", "updated_at"=>"2019-08-06T17:30:47.372-03:00", "phone"=>"(21)999999999"}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, the serializer's name is singular, i.e. `DevelopmentAgentSerializer` instead of `DevelopmentAgentsSerializer` (Don't forget to also change the file name). If this convention is not followed, the serializer you defined won't be used, and the response will just be `@development_agents.as_json`